# Do tag-only edits add value to questions?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits, suggested-edits

The Stack Overflow "[How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" page recommends that questions should "include *all relevant tags*". And to "try to include a tag for the *language*, library, and specific API your question relates to."

SO states that "[tags are a means of connecting experts with questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)…".

The [Organizer badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/5/organizer) is awarded specifically for retagging.

It certainly appears that the developers of SO feel tags are an important feature of the website.

It seems, however, some reviewers automatically reject tag-only edits as "too minor". **If a question relates to a specific tag, shouldn't that tag be included in the question?**

For example, if a question includes jQuery code and requires an answer using jQuery, and the OP didn’t include the [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) tag, **does adding the [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) tag add value to the question**?